# laravel swf file path cannot find

Tags: javascript, php, flash, laravel-4, webcam

I have a webcam.js and webcam.swf located at public/assets/cam/ in laravel.

In my page.blade.php, there is a part where i included webcam.js

```
{{ HTML::script('assets/cam/webcam.js') }}
```

The webcam.js work is to use or locate the webcam.swf so that the webcam will show on my laptop screen.

```
window.webcam = {
version: '1.0.9',

// globals
ie: !!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/),
protocol: location.protocol.match(/https/i) ? 'https' : 'http',
callback: null, // user callback for completed uploads
swf_url: 'webcam.swf', // URI to webcam.swf movie (defaults to cwd)
shutter_url: 'shutter.mp3', // URI to shutter.mp3 sound
api_url: '', // URL to upload script
loaded: false, // true when webcam movie finishes loading
quality: 90, // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
shutter_sound: true, // shutter sound effect on/off
stealth: false, // stealth mode (do not freeze image upon capture)
hooks: {
    onLoad: null,
    onComplete: null,
    onError: null
}
```

This should work base on the tutorial i am following. But i guess there is a problem with the swf_url since it is in laravel. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code is not able to reach `webcam.swf`. Create JS variable for storing the path and append it with the path to `webcam.swf`. Something like this:

```
// Something like this
var base_url = '<?php echo URL::base(); ?>';

swf_url: base_url + 'webcam.swf', // URI to webcam.swf movie (defaults to cwd)
```

Same for other urls.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but still it's not working. I am using laravel 4.1 and i think URL::base() is not included with the version.

Yeah, it doesn't reach the webcam.swf in webcam.js file.

Comment: If `webcam.swf` is not reachable then the solution remains the same, use the URI method which is included in your version of Laravel.